# Adding some html to body tag with append but html's id not execute

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome-extension

I have added some html to body tag with append. But When I put  `runOCR(url)` ,All function stop working.How to come up from this problem.

Here Is My Code:

```
function body(){
  if (window.location.hostname.match(/www.w3schools.com/)){

   var large = '<div class="form-group"> \
   <input type="text" id="url" placeholder="Image URL" />\
     <div id="ocr_status"> </div>\
     <div>\
        <label>Filed1:</label>\
           <textarea id="text1" ></textarea>\
     </div>\

     </div>' ;


    $('body').append(large);

     $(".form-group").css({
     position: "fixed",
    top: "20px",
    right: "180px",
    'border-radius': '25px',
    'border': '2px solid #73AD21',
     'padding': '20px', 
      'background': 'blue',

       "font-size": "1.5em",
       "z-index": "1000",

          });

     function runOCR(url) {
  Tesseract.recognize(url)
  .then(function(result) {
  document.getElementById("text1")
  .innerHTML = result.text;
  document.getElementById('text1').focus();

  }).progress(function(result) {
  document.getElementById("ocr_status")
  .innerText = result["status"] + " (" +
  (result["progress"] * 100) + "%)";
  });
  }
  document.getElementById("url")
  .addEventListener("input", function(e) {
  var url = document.getElementById("url").value;
  runOCR(url);
```

Comment: The code is fine syntax-wise, but if this is inside a *content script*, you can't use `onclick` attributes to point to your functions because your script is running inside an isolated world. Instead attach the listeners programmatically afterwards: $('.form-group button').on('click', splitText)

Comment: but splitText() with ${i} is working normal html file.

Comment: @daddygames: as of EcmaScript 2015, [that is something](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) Javascript will do by itself.

Comment: @wOxxOm  thanks now working.

Comment: @StriplingWarrior Okay. I guess I missed this update. I'm assuming because I always have had to support IE in all of my apps thus far and that feature is not supported by IE (any version). Thank you for pointing that out to me.

Comment: @wOxxOm dear sir, can you help me, of the recent update.